# What is Report ID used for in SSRS reports?

Tags: ssrs, report

While looking the XML file of my solution I saw this

[image]

Does this ID have any practical use or is only for internal use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that is a local .rdlc file.

IMHO it has not practical use, in fact you can copy & paste as a new report using the same ReportID and it works.

[Is it safe to create new .RDLC report as a copy of existing .RDLC report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52995828/is-it-safe-to-create-new-rdlc-report-as-a-copy-of-existing-rdlc-report)

If you have a look at: [RDL XML Schema for Version 2016/01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-rdl/52ce3983-2bfc-4e72-9359-42aaf5fe4509) you won't find any reference to the `<ReportID>` tag, or if you get the RDL definition of any report stored in SSRS database, ([Where does a published RDL file sit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068307/3270427)), you won't be able to find this tag into the file definition.